# Set reflect.Value to slice in Go

Tags: loops, go, pointers, cypher, reflect

I try to save a slice of integers of a field. the field is type reflect.Value.

I get the error: cannot use articles (variable of type []int64) as reflect.Value value in argument to field.Set. What can I do to encounter that?

Thank you very much!

```
for i := 0; i < elem.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        structField := elem.Type().Field(i)

        tag := structField.Tag.Get("db")
        fieldType := structField.Type
        fieldName := structField.Name
        val, ok := record.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s", tag))
        if ok {
            // Ignore nil values
            if val == nil {
                continue
            }
            field := elem.FieldByName(fieldName)
            if field.IsValid() {
                t := fieldType.String()
                switch t {
                case "string":
                    field.SetString(val.(string))
                case "int64":
                    field.SetInt(val.(int64))
                case "float64":
                    field.SetFloat(val.(float64))
                case "boolean":
                    field.SetBool(val.(bool))
                case "[]int64":
                    articles := []int64{}
                    initData := []interface{}{
                        val,
                    }
                    for _, data := range initData {
                        for _, v := range data.([]interface{}) {
                            t := v
                            articles = append(articles, t.(int64))
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    field.Set(articles)
                default:
                    return fmt.Errorf("Invalid type: %s", t)
                }

            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Do NOT post images of text. You should share your code as text. StackOverflow supports syntax highlighting, use that. `ptr` is unexported (starts with lower-case), Go does not allow to access unexported members from outside of the package in which they are declared. You can access only exported members (those that start with upper-case). `reflect.Value` has a `Set` method that you can use to set a value of any type that **is assignable** to its receiver. (https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.18.3#Value.Set).

Comment: Thank you for you advice!. I tried to use field.Set(), but I get now this error: cannot use articles (variable of type []int64) as reflect.Value value in argument to field.Set. 
What can I do?

Comment: `field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(articles))`

Answer (score 1):

The answer of mkopriva: field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(articles))